# Complex css selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors

Hello I need to get CSS selector after active class, for example:
if I have 7 `div` and one of them have active class I need to get the fourth element after active class.

```
<div>1</div>
<div class="active">2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div> <!-- I need to get this selector -->
<div>7</div>
```

Comment: Just have a look at the [CSS selector reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) and try [the `+` selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp). It does not sound all that complex to me. Could you add some more detail about what you are struggling with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [**`+`** selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp)

```css
.active + div + div + div + div {
background:red;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div class="active">2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div> <!-- I need to get this selector -->
<div>7</div>
```

Comment: @ValDo only forward selection.